# Javascript array doesn't fill correctly because asyncrous method from Firestore

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-cloud-firestore

I have a big problem filling a table with some information from firestore database.
I need to consult two collections, one inside first one.

I have a function that returns my principal array:

```
llista(ordre) {
    Loading.fadeIn('Carregant taula...');
    return db
        .collection('alumnes')
        .orderBy('cognoms', ordre)
        .get()
        .then(function (doc) {
            var llistaAlumnes = new Array();
            doc.forEach((alumne) => {
                var assistencia = Alumnes.assistencia(alumne.id);
                assistencia.then((assistencies) => {
                    var ass = new Array();
                    $.each(assistencies, function (i, val) {
                        ass.push([val[0], val[1]]);
                    });
                });

                llistaAlumnes.push({
                    id: alumne.id,
                    nomComplet: alumne.data().nom + ' ' + alumne.data().cognoms,
                    assistencia: ass
                });
            });
            return llistaAlumnes;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

and the second method inside this Alumnes Class:

```
static assistencia(id) {
    return db
        .collection('alumnes')
        .doc(id)
        .collection('assistencia')
        .get()
        .then(function (doc) {
            var assistencia = new Array();
            doc.forEach((doc) => {
                assistencia.push(new Array(doc.id, doc.data().assistencia));
            });
            return assistencia;
        });
}
```

I call this first method **llista** by this code:

```
var llista = alumnes.llista('asc');
llista.then((llistaAlumnes) => {
    $.each(llistaAlumnes, function (i, val) {
        $('#tbl-assistencia tbody').append('<tr id="' + val.id + '"><th class="bg-light" style="width:100%">' + val.nomComplet + '</td></tr>');
        console.log(val.ass);

        if (llistaAlumnes.length === i + 1) {
            $.each(allDies, function (i, date) {
                afegirColumnaAssistencia(llistaAlumnes, date);
                if (allDies.length === i + 1) {
                    taulaAssistencia();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The basic problem is that when I colsole this val.assistencia it returns *Promise {pending}* and I can't see the error because I think that I'm waiting for two methods ends each for continue before fill the table.

**edit**
My problem is that i need to insert this ass array inside my llisstaAlumnes array, but I don't know how to do that syncrous and wait untill all each ends.

I edit my code for what I need, return my main array llistaAlumnes with a subarray inside with two dimensions variables like.

I need do it before fill the table and for that I need a llistaAlumnes array like (example)

```
[llistaAlumnes]
     id: 6syyfhan3j12,
     nomComplet: John Smith,
     assistencia: [26/05/2020,good][27/05/2020,bad]
```

Anyone can helps me please? Thanks!

**Edit** 07/07/2020
I tried everything but I can't get my result before all and then do anything. Nothing then, If nobody answer my question in the next week, I'll delete this thread, so, it's not solved and does not contribute anything in this community.

Comment: You never use `ass`. Isn't that what you want for the property value? That is only part of the problem but needs clarifying

Comment: yes sorry, i need push `ass` in my `llistaAlumnes` array but i don't know how to do that. I try all methods but nothing works, I miss anything.

Comment: Editted code for better clarify!

Comment: Do some research into how to `map()` your promises instead of doing foreach and then use `promise.All(promisesArray)` to work with array of all results nd to move on to next step

Comment: mmm.. I'm new in promises. Can you explain me with some example?

Comment: Well everything that has a `then()` is a promise. From there do some research into Promise.all() and "javascript map promise array" or similar queries. Really need to understand promises to do what you are doing with lots of nested asynchronous promise operations

Comment: If you need help using promises, take a look at the official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions